# sum lines with similar substring

Tags: r, perl

I have a data frame (tab-sep) that contain counts and sub-IDs that are identical. 
I would like to combine the counts for all identical sub-IDs. Please see example. 
in:

```
IsomiR                                  185R 68G 60G 134G 124R
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCCT     1   6   1   2   2
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTT      1   0   1   1   4
hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTC     4   5   2   12  4
hsa-let-7b-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCC    7   5   2   6   3
hsa-let-7b-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT    15  6   14  49  32
hsa-let-7b-3p_CCATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT    4   1   1   0   0
hsa-let-7b-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTT       2   2   1   2   3
hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTT      29  7   26  21  19
hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTTC     85  24  73  109 59
hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCA    11  3   7   8   3
```

out:

```
IsomiR          185R 68G 60G 134G 124R
hsa-let-7a-3p   6    11  4   15   10
hsa-let-7b-3p   28   ..  ..  ..   ..
hsa-let-7c-3p   ..
```

Comment: Although there is already an accepted answer, it would be nice to see that you invested time into solving your own problems. Just asking for someone to do it for you is not very nice, considering there are real people that invest their real, valueable time to help a random stranger on the internet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could match the substring starting from `_` to the end of the string (`.*$`) in 'IsomiR' column and replace with `''` using `sub`.  We use that as the grouping variable.  If we are doing this with `dplyr`, the `summarise_each` can be used for `sum`ming multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(IsomiR= sub('_.*$', '', IsomiR)) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
#         IsomiR X185R X68G X60G X134G X124R
#1 hsa-let-7a-3p     6   11    4    15    10
#2 hsa-let-7b-3p    28   14   18    57    38
#3 hsa-let-7c-3p   125   34  106   138    81
```

Or we can use `separate` from `tidyr` where we split the 'IsomiR' column into by specifying the `sep='_'`, use that as grouping variable, and in the `summarise_each` we can `select` the columns using regex pattern in the `matches`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, IsomiR, into=c('IsomiR', 'unWanted'), sep='_') %>%
             group_by(IsomiR) %>%
             summarise_each(funs(sum), matches('[0-9]+[A-Z]$'))
```

---

Using data.table, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Remove the substring in 'IsomiR' with `sub`, use that as a grouping variable, loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ..)`) and get the `sum` (suggested by @David Arenburg in the comments).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(IsomiR = sub('_.*', '', IsomiR))]
```

---

Or another option is the formula method in `aggregate` from `baseR` after we `transform` the original dataset  column 'IsomiR` as described above.

```
 aggregate(.~IsomiR, transform(df1, IsomiR= sub('_.*', '', IsomiR)), sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(IsomiR = c("hsa-let-7a-3p_ATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCCT", 
"hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTT", 
"hsa-let-7a-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTC", 
"hsa-let-7b-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCC",
"hsa-let-7b-3p_ATATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT", 
"hsa-let-7b-3p_CCATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCT", "hsa-let-7b-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTT", 
"hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTT", "hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTTC",    
"hsa-let-7c-3p_CTATACAATCTACTGTCTTTCA"), X185R = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 
 7L, 15L, 4L, 2L, 29L, 85L, 11L), X68G = c(6L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 24L, 3L), X60G = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 
73L, 7L), X134G = c(2L, 1L, 12L, 6L, 49L, 0L, 2L, 21L, 109L, 
8L), X124R = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 32L, 0L, 3L, 19L, 59L, 3L)),
.Names = c("IsomiR", 
 "X185R", "X68G", "X60G", "X134G", "X124R"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Arghhh... was just posting `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(IsomiR = sub('_.*', '', IsomiR))]`. Beware of this OP though, he always says that the solution doesn't work. Even if it perfectly does. So prepare for a rain of bs.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Are you going to post that as a separate answer?

Comment: No, the OP will claim it doesn't work. I've already spent too much time on him [on his previous bs question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32178531/3001626). You can post it though.

Comment: I was going to post `aggregate(df[-1], list(gsub("_.*", "", df$IsomiR)), sum)` Save a keystroke or two